# Azure Search Autocomplete Fuzzy

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Using autocomplete with fuzzy search

Tried using both Get and Post in the Autocomplete API

POST ->

https://service.search.windows.net/indexes/index/docs/autocomplete?api-version=2019-05-06

Body -> 
{
  "autocompleteMode": "oneTermWithContext",
  "fuzzy": true,
  "search": "Chinz",
  "suggesterName": "sg"
}

Chinz should fuzzy search to China or Chins? or something... but it gets nothing

if I put Chin the first thing that comes out is China, then Chinese

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

If I use the Suggest? api the Fuzzy works but I'm looking for single terms only

Also, this doesn't work through C# either. With UseFuzzyMatching = True.

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of your index?

Fuzzy matching in autocomplete works better on indexes with more documents. Autocomplete queries first look for terms in the inverted index that matched given prefix. To that list we add terms from the inverted index that are within edit distance of 1 from the matched terms.

Azure Search indexes are split into multiple inverted indexes to enable efficient scale out operations. It can happen that in a small Azure Search index individual inverted indexes don’t contain all terms that exist in the data corpus what can lead to unexpected results. This is a limitation we’re aware of and a compromise we need to make between intuitive behavior and service scalability.

Comment: Only about 100000